# PowerShell Class Inheritance from separate file using Import-Module

Tags: class, powershell, inheritance

What am I doing wrong here - or does PowerShell v5 not support separate class files and inheritance?

foo.ps1:

```
class foo
{
   [STRING] $test = 'Hello World';

   [STRING] PrintTest()
   {
      return $this.test;
   }
}
```

bar.ps1:

```
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\foo.ps1"

class bar : foo
{ }
```

**CONSOLE**

```
PS C:\Script> Import-Module ./bar.ps1;

PS C:\Script> $myBar = New-Object bar;

PS C:\Script> $myBar.PrintTest();

Method invocation failed because [bar] does not contain a method named 'PrintTest'.
```

If it put the foo and bar classes in the same file it works fine. However the classes I'm building are rather large and I want to separate them.

Comment: Are you sure about error, which you are getting? I would expect `ParseError` on `Import-Module ./bar.ps1`, if you do that from clean PowerShell session.

Comment: Yep, it loads bar.ps1 with no errors. Even creates the bar object with no issues.

Comment: classes are not exported with modules. See my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, a module file should have the extension `.psm1` so you're going to want to change that. If you do not name them this way, the `Using` statement I referenced below will show an error.

bar.psm1 should contain a reference to the module, because [modules do not import classes](https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-classes/import-powershell-classes-from-modules).

bar.psm1:

```
Using module ".\foo.psm1"

class bar : foo
{ }
```

However once you do this, the bar class is not exported so you would have to write a separate ps1 file that stated at the top `Using module ".\bar.psm1"` and then inside that script file you could call the [bar] class.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I know I was missing something simple.